# SQL replace dirty_name from Full_Name to standard_Name

Tags: sql, join, replace, left-join, union

i want to trim dity_name from Student first name and replace it with Standard_Name.

actually i am having a lookup table named "Name_Lookup_Table" containg field Standard_name and dirty_name

as in this part of query i find Dirty_Name from loopup table in student_first name. 
`tas.Student_First_Name like '% '+nlt.Dirty_Name`

now i want to replace this dirty_name with standard_name in the student_first_name

how should i do this??

i am try this but standard name is not fitting in the right place for where it is extracted

```
SELECT Student_First_Name
    ,concat(LEFT(Student_First_Name , LEN(Student_First_Name)-LEN(nlt.Dirty_Name)),nlt.Standard_Name)
    , nlt.Dirty_Name
    , nlt.Standard_Name


FROM Transformed_All_Student tas
        LEFT JOIN Name_Lookup_Table nlt
                    ON tas.Student_First_Name like '% '+nlt.Dirty_Name
WHERE tas.Student_First_Name like '% '+nlt.Dirty_Name


UNION

   SELECT Student_First_Name
 ,concat(nlt.Standard_Name,LEFT(Student_First_Name , LEN(Student_First_Name)-LEN(nlt.Dirty_Name)))
         , nlt.Dirty_Name
        , nlt.Standard_Name
    FROM Transformed_All_Student tas 
            LEFT JOIN Name_Lookup_Table nlt 
                    ON tas.Student_First_Name like nlt.Dirty_Name+' % '

WHERE tas.Student_First_Name like nlt.Dirty_Name+' % '

    UNION

SELECT Student_First_Name
    ,concat(LEFT(Student_First_Name , LEN(Student_First_Name)-LEN(nlt.Dirty_Name)),nlt.Standard_Name)        
    , nlt.Dirty_Name
    , nlt.Standard_Name

FROM Transformed_All_Student tas 
        LEFT JOIN Name_Lookup_Table nlt 
            ON tas.Student_First_Name like '% '+nlt.Dirty_Name+' % '

WHERE tas.Student_First_Name like '% '+nlt.Dirty_Name+' %'
```

p.s Dirty_name and Standard_name from loopup table can be of variable lenght

output:

```
Full_Name             Replaced_Name        Dirty_Name     Standard_Name
1. Abdul              Adul                 Abdul          Adul
2. Mouhammad Saroor   MouhammMohammad      Mouhammad      Mohammad
3. Rashid             Rasheed              Rashid         Rasheed
4. Salim              Saleem               Salim          Saleem
5. Sh. Yaseen         Sh. YasSheikh        Sh.            Sheikh
```

Output of row 2 ans 4 is incorrect. 
in row two replaced_Name should be Mohammad Saroor 
and in row 4 replaced_Name should be Sheikh Yaseen :S

replace_name is coming from query: 
`concat(LEFT(Student_First_Name , LEN(Student_First_Name)-LEN(nlt.Dirty_Name)),nlt.Standard_Name)`

Comment: i am concatenating her but it is not placing the standard name in right place because of variable length of dirty_name and standard_name
plus it is not replacing the dirty name its just overwriting.

Comment: What do you mean StandardName is not fitting? Can you give an example of the output?

Comment: <blink>Full_Name         replaced_Name      Dirty_Name        Standard_name

Adul              Abdul           Adul            Abdul
Mouhammad Saroor   MouhammMohammad  Mouhammad Mohammad 
 Rashid      Rasheed         Rashid          Rasheed
 Salim              Saleem           Salim           Saleem 
</blink>
Record on 2nd row is incorrect i want this mouhammad saroor name to be as Mohammad saroor i.e mouhammad should be replaced by MUHAMMAD

Comment: @Melanie
one name which comes in output after replacing is " MouhammMohammad " but the original name was mouhammad saroor i want this mouhammad saroor name to be as Mohammad saroor i.e mouhammad should be replaced by MUHAMMAD. but this query giving me output "MouhammMohammad" instead of "Mohammad saroor"

Comment: When you're posting code, it's easiest to go back and edit your original question. What you post in a comment isn't very easy to read. Please give original input, what you what the output to be, and what the output is. Thanks!

Comment: @Melanie i edited the code with output you asked to make question clear to you :)